# JavaCompiler from inside a jar

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jar

my JavaCompiler returns a null pointer when called from a jar file.

Everything works fine if I run my program with the JavaCompiler from command line.
So the JDK is properly installed on my OS.

Why isn't it working?

Code:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable<String> options = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "-d", currentDir+"/cache/","-sourcepath",currentDir+"/srcss/"} );
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compUnits =  fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(fRun);
Boolean compRes = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, options, null, compUnits).call();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're using the same runtime when launching the application as a jar.

When launching it as a stand alone application you're probably using `rt.jar` from some basic JRE installation, while when you execute it from an IDE you're most likely using an `rt.jar` from the JDK.

You could do `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));` to debug this.

Comment: But my system is set to the JDK. When I launch my program from Command Line it starts from the JDK. How to set the jar to JDK?

Comment: Print the string returned by `System.getProperty("java.home")` in your application and see if it differs.

Answer (score 0):

It it is your own deployment (to your own machine), the problem can be solved by explicitly adding the `tools.jar` of the SDK to the run-time class-path of your application (e.g. mention it in the manifest).

Alternative strategies can be seen (or are at least hinted at) in the [STBC configuration](http://pscode.org/stbc/help.html).  If you need more info. on those, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As Per my understanding, JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); Returns the Handle to java compiler only if its beign executed under and JDK distribution.

if you are using it under JRE (as normally we execute under JRE only) it would return null, could you please confirm that we are calling it from JDK or it contains the appropriate jar file in place